# PHP bindtextdomain fails

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I am trying to setup internationalization in PHP on a CentOS server running PHP 7.1

Here is my directory structure:

```
/home/project/public_html/locale/japanese/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po 
/home/project/public_html/locale/japanese/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
/home/project/public_html/index.php
```

the messages.po containst the line (among others):

```
"Language: japanese\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

I have the following code:

```
$check_putenv = putenv("LC_ALL=japanese");
if (!$check_putenv) {
    echo "Warning: putenv LC_ALL failed!\n";
}

$check_putenv2 = putenv("LANGUAGE=japanese");
if (!$check_putenv2) {
    echo "Warning: putenv LANGUAGE failed!\n";
}    

$check_locale = setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'japanese');
if (!$check_locale) {
    echo "Warning: Failed to set locale japanese!\n";
}
$check_bind = bindtextdomain("messages", "/home/project/public_html/locale");
if (!$check_bind) {
    echo "Warning: Failed to bind text domain!\n";
}
$check_textdomain = textdomain("messages");
if ($check_textdomain !== "messages") {
    echo "Warning: Failed to set text domain!\n";
}
```

the output is

```
Warning: Failed to bind text domain!
```

locale -a returns (among others)

```
ja_JP
ja_JP.utf8
japanese
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `$lang = 'ja_JP'` or `ja_JP.UTF-8` (and using this variable in all the settings and directory name)?

Comment: See also languages and regions in http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

Comment: And have you installed the japanese language-pack on your system via repository management? Reconfigured (creating) locales after that?

Comment: As by edit shown, even if "japanese" alias is installed on the system, I'm not sure whether or not the PHP implementation of gettext accepts this.

Comment: Thanks, ja_JP.UTF-8 works!

Comment: Ok, I've supplied a summarizing answer to the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the *gettext* extension relies on the standard locale specifiers containing the language and region code, i.e. `ja_JP` for "Japanese in Japan" or with the specified encoding `ja_JP.utf-8`. Even if there is an alias like `japanese`, the PHP implementation of gettext does not accept this. Note that the locale has to be installed and configured on your system.

Language and region specifiers can be found in [IANA language-subtag-registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry)

This code already should work for the Japanese language:

```
$dir     = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/locale';
$domain  = 'messages';
$locale  = 'ja_JP.utf8';
$codeset = 'UTF-8';

setlocale( LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
bindtextdomain($domain, $dir);
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $codeset);
```

Remember to also rename your directory into `locale/ja_JP.utf8`. Ensure your .po files are stored with the correct encoding, i.e. `UTF-8` in this example, and contain the line

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

(as you already have done).

Comment: This code solved my issue. Thanks.

`bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $codeset)`