# gettext and bindtextdomain doesn't translate

Tags: php, gettext

I am trying to translate some texts to Japanese. But couldn't translate it. even it doesn't throw any error. according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php bindtextdomain() should look for .mo file. when I debug my code ir returns `/var/www/lumber-mill.co.jp/sys/locales` is it the problem of not being translated?

I followed these-
[PHP bindtextdomain fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251911/php-bindtextdomain-fails)

[Gettext doesn't translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482575/gettext-doesnt-translate)

none of these solved my problem. How can I solve it?

```
<?php
function __autoload($class) {
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../core/" . $class . ".php";
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        include_once $filename;
    }else{
        $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../toolkit/" . $class . ".php";
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            include_once $filename;
        }
    }
}

// タイムゾーンと言語設定

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
session_start();

if (isset($_GET["lang"])) {
    // パラメタで直接指定されている場合
    switch ($_GET["lang"]) {
        case "en_US":
        case "ja_JP":
            $_SESSION["LANGUAGE"] = $_GET["lang"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} else if (!isset($_SESSION["LANGUAGE"])) {
    // セッションに定義されていない場合、リクエストヘッダから判別します
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
        $languages = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
        $languages = array_reverse($languages);
    } else {
        $languages = array();
    }

    $lang = 'ja_JP'; // 規定値
    foreach ($languages as $language) {
        if (preg_match('/^ja/i', $language)) {
            $lang = 'ja_JP';
        } elseif (preg_match('/^en/i', $language)) {
            $lang = 'en_US';
        }
    }
    $_SESSION["LANGUAGE"] = $lang;
}

// 言語設定
setlocale(LC_ALL, $_SESSION["LANGUAGE"] . '.utf8');
$res = bindtextdomain("messages", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../sys/locales");
$mes = textdomain("messages");
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8');
print_r($res);
print_r($mes);

// 動作環境
if(strpos($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"],"dev.") === 0){
  define("ENV","staging");
}else{
  define("ENV","production");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was solved when I just added the following line- 
`putenv("LANGUAGE=".$_SESSION["LANGUAGE"].".utf8");`